# Ace Editor: Disable converting of certain ACSII characters, ie &lt to <

Tags: ascii, ace-editor

I'm using Ace editor as a on-site HTML editor. I have a problem with some characters being automatically converted by Ace Editor.

I use "&lt" a lot on some of my pages, so I can display HTML snippets as text, rather than processing the HTML. Ace Editor is converting these to "<" automatically.

Is there a way I can disable this behavior?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Converting `&lt;` to `<` is a default browser behavior. you need to use `&amp;lt;` to get `&lt;`.
Try `<textarea> &lt; &amp;lt;</textarea>` to see that the same happens without ace.

Comment: I know it can be worked around; that's what I do now, but it's problematic. I'm really wondering if Ace can do this automatically, ie, display the ACTUAL text rather than the HTML for everything within the editor, as it does with whitespace / tabs.

Comment: when you call ace.edit text content is already converted
you can use <xmp> tag like http://jsbin.com/ojijeb/97/edit
or load textcontent with js or use string.replace